# How to schedule a Cloud Datastore export with App Engine in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-datastore

I have an app which stores user data in GCP Datastore.
I have made a cron job that is scheduled to export the data in Datastore using the instructions given [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export).

However, I need to change python2 to python3.

According to [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export),app uses a app_identity library to obtain tokens.

```
    from google.appengine.api import app_identity
    access_token, _ = app_identity.get_access_token('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore')
```

But this library is not supported in python3 according to [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/).

How can I get a access_token in python3?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not supported ? for me that's just their documentation that is not up-to-date. The app_identity should have its correspondent in python3

Comment: Importing google.appengine gives error as error in python3:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'

Comment: https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) library. It's supported in python 3 and makes it easy to build requests for the Cloud Datastore API.

Another thing you'll need to change is the `webapp2` library since it's also not supported in python 3. You can replace it with something like Flask.

Here's an example of the app rewritten for python 3:

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

(deploy to a non-default service if needed with `service: service_name`)

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask
google-api-python-client
```

**main.py**

```
import datetime
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'    

@app.route('/cloud-datastore-export')
def export():
    # Deny if not from the Cron Service
    assert request.headers['X-Appengine-Cron']
    # Deny if output_url_prefix not set correctly
    output_url_prefix = request.args.get('output_url_prefix')
    assert output_url_prefix and output_url_prefix.startswith('gs://')
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
    if '/' not in output_url_prefix[5:]:
      # Only a bucket name has been provided - no prefix or trailing slash
      output_url_prefix += '/' + timestamp
    else:
      output_url_prefix += timestamp
    kinds = request.args.getlist('kind')
    namespace_ids = request.args.getlist('namespace_id')
    entity_filter = {
        'kinds': kinds,
        'namespace_ids': namespace_ids 
    }
    body = {
        'output_url_prefix': output_url_prefix,
        'entity_filter': entity_filter
    }
    project_id = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT')
    client = build('datastore', 'v1')
    client.projects().export(projectId=project_id, body=body).execute()  
    return 'Operation started' 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally only. When deploying to Google App
    # Engine, a webserver process such as Gunicorn will serve the app. This
    # can be configured by adding an `entrypoint` to app.yaml.
    # Flask's development server will automatically serve static files in
    # the "static" directory. See:
    # http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#static-files. Once deployed,
    # App Engine itself will serve those files as configured in app.yaml.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```